# What components can I throw in the trash?

Tags: components

I did some repairs on a project of mine and replaced a handful of MOSFETs. It occurred to me that I don't know if I can just throw the old ones in the trash or if I should take them to a recycling station?

More generally, what classes of components can be thrown away and which need special treatment?

I live in Europe, specifically Sweden, but answers for other parts of the world might be interesting as well.

Comment: Well, as a general rule *all* of the components should go to the "electronic waste" class.

Comment: The recycling station will just send them to China, where they will go in the trash. Next to a giant new coal fired power station.

Comment: The first environmental concern with electronic components that comes to mind is [heavy metals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_metals).

Comment: I do not know the answer to your question. But whatever you do, don't let them get mixed back in with good parts.